# How to fight network latency and jitter issues on Wifi?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, latency, wifi-driver

I'm having problems with my Wifi connection.

I did a test on [PingTest.net](http://pingtest.net) with the following results:

```
Packet Loss: 0%
Ping: 103ms
Jitter: 29ms
```

Same test but from another machine on the network resulted in much less numbers for Ping (17ms) and Jitter (1ms). 
I updated my driver for the wireless card with the latest available.

I'm using Intel Ultimate-N 6300 AGN adapter (Win7/64bit) and D-Link 855L wireless router. WiFi configured for WPA2 N-only connection. I'm also using 'less crowded' channel.

Below is the `ping` statistics between my machine and the router:

```
Ping statistics for 192.168.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 3603, Received = 3535, Lost = 68 (1% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 1ms, Maximum = 1746ms, Average = 13ms
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: much of this is going to be related to environmental conditions like the location of the device relative to the wifi ap (walls, metal/concrete girders), and ambient interference (fluorescent lighting, wall power lines, high power devices). how much do the readings change if you do the test of both devices from the same location?

Comment: @FrankThomas I tested both computers in front of the router (both computers are laptops) in the same room.

Comment: if they have the same network card and driver then, it must come down to a characteristic of the laptops themselves.

Comment: What network configuration/hardware does the machine with better performance have?

Comment: @NevinWilliams Machine with better performance has Intel advanced-N 6250 wireless card (built-in). I also noticed that on my machine I have Dropbox installed and when I pause syncing pingtest.net gives me better results

Comment: How much better?  It does indeed look like the inherent capabilities of the machines;   How about when wired?

Comment: @NevinWilliams On the wired network everything was perfect. I'm completely confused now. I did the same test (went to use pingtest.net) with this laptop at work and got amazing results. Don't want to come to a quick conclusion yet...Will try to post my router's configs later today

Comment: I played with the settings on the router (sorry, couldn't upload screens to the site) and came to the conclusion that it is something to do with the adapter/Windows combination since everything works just fine on other machines. Will see if the newer driver fixes the issue

Answer (score 4):

The root cause of jitter and latency on a WIFI network is a combination of available bandwidth, number of people using the connection and interference - thus to improve latency you need to improve these aspects.   Jitter is caused by variance in the amount of bandwidth being used.

As general rules (as they apply to a LAN WIFI) -

The lower the speed of the connection the higher the latency.
The more interference the lower the available bandwidth.
The more people using the connection the greater the jitter.
The more interference from other devices which are not always transmitting, the greater the jitter.

Things you can do -

- Get better hardware. Better hardware could be hardware which obeys newer standards (which make better use of the spectrum), and/or are more sensitive - ie better signal to noise ratio, which can improve throughput.
- Reduce heavy users.   Try and connect heavy users via a cable - this will give them better performance and take load off the WIFI.
- Use alternative technologies where practical - ethernet is great. Powerline over Internet can be useful as well.
- Play nice with your neighbours.  If you can work together to allocate frequency and share an SSID you can all get better coverage and your equipment can better handle timing of signals.
- Use more higher gain / directional aerials - this will create a louder signal - so more throughput in the directions of interest.  Note that higher gain aerials are generally more directional (they often give a larger radius but less height)
- Channel Bond - Newer devices will allow you to have 40 megabit channels on the 2.4 gig band and up to 160 megabit on the 5 gig band.  More bandwidth = lower latency.
- Isolate your network - this may not be practical, but running mesh arround your property and grounding it can apparently make a big difference to noise from your neighbors.
- Don't use repeaters.  These waste bandwidth.  Rather set up multiple APs on different frequencies (3 channels or more apart), and connect via ethernet or powerline.
- Deploy more access points.  This will increase the signal and provide more bandwidth, thus reducing jitter and latency.
- Make sure your WIFI drivers are good - WIFI drivers can be a bit hit and miss - and they can very much affect latency and jitter.

There are other things you can do as well - but they may not work so well on a LAN -

- You can implement QoS - by better scheduling packets you can reduce jitter and make better use of available frequency.  You may also be able to reduce latency.  Unfortunately this works better on the sender side, which you have less control of in this environment.
- Fragment packets (ie use a smaller MTU).   This will reduce latency but also decrease speed.  Its also not easy to do and can break connectivity.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, i wanna tell you if jitter and ping is lesser your internet is more smother.

ping should be 1-2ms.
jitter also should be around 1-2ms
loss - 0.0%